# How to use Linq to Entity to query results ordered by field in related table in C# windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have 2 Tables in SQL server database :

```
Table1:
  CustomerID
  CustomerName
Table2:
  TicketID
  TicketDate
  CustomerID
```

related using One(Table1) to Many (Table2)

I want to make linq to entities query using C# to query all customers ORDERED BY TicketDate descending, so that i can list all DISTINCT names of customers in combobox with customers who have most recent tickets viewed at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Table2 doesn't have 10+ times the number of records of Customer you can change things around. OrderBy Tickets and select Customer

```
//Gets a list of all customers, sorted by ticket date
List<Table1> customers = entities.Table2
.OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketDate)
.Select(t => t.Table1)
.Distinct()
.ToList();
```

If Table2 has a lot more records (10+ times the number of records or just billions) you should start with Customer and use Max date, so the query on the database does the same and doesn't do an exact reordering for each Customer.

```
 List<Table1> customers = entities.Table1
.OrderByDescending(c => c.Table2.Max(t => t.TicketDate))
.ToList();
```

**EDIT**

I think this is the option that you should use, since it doesn't result in a subquery per record to determine MAX, but performs MAX on each group

```
List<Table1> customers = entities.Table2
.GroupBy(t => t.Table1)
.OrderByDescending(g => g.Max(t => t.TicketDate))
.Select(g => g.Key)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Putting .Distinct() seems to cancel the action of .OrderbyDescending

Comment: Check my answer. I added a third option which is best in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, is this what you are looking for?

```
using (DatabaseEntities entities = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    //Gets a list of all customers, sorted by ticket date
    List<Table1> customers = entities.Table1
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Table2.Select(y => y.TicketDate).OrderByDescending(y => y.TicketDate)
    .FirstOrDefault().TicketDate)
    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: It works nice for listing customers ordered by TicketDate, but putting .Distinct() in code for some reason makes the ordering process wrong

Comment: I've had another go, this time rearranging the query so that the customers are loaded, then sorted by the latest ticket that exists for them, hopefully this will be better: `    List<Table1> customers = entities.Table1
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Table2.Select(y => y.TicketDate).OrderByDescending(y => y.TicketDate).FirstOrDefault().TicketDate)
    .ToList();`